# phpmailer error codes for outcome processing

Tags: email, phpmailer

I am building a mailout capability and it is working OK as far as it goes.  However, I want to distinguish between various potential (high level) outcomes in order to determine what happens to each message after the current send attempt.

This must be a common requirement so I seem to be missing something pretty obvious, but I can't find anything that addresses it, either here or via Google or on PHPMailer site or .. .  Possibly because there are so many questions about specific errors that I just can't find anything useful in all the other results.

At very high level:
Attempt send, and assess resulting error/result.  Identify whether this message has been sent, must be retried later, or failed permanently.
- success -> update message status as 'SENT: OK'
- sent, but some issues (e.g. one recipient failed, others processed OK)-> 'SENT: some error'
- failed, due to temporary problem (e.g. connection problem, attachment open) -> 'TRY LATER'
- failed, due to message-specific problem that we should NOT try to resend-> 'FAILED: some error'

As I was unable to find an existing resource with e.g. a table of errors, I spent some time working through the phpmailerException code to try to build one myself, but it's not simple because a) they don't appear to have been designed in terms of this kind of grouping logic, b) it is not easy to uniquely identify a particular error: PHPMailer provides human-friendly messages, which are different in different languages, rather than an identifiable code - given that my solution will need to work across different language installations that's a problem!

Obviously SMTP itself provides a range of errorcodes which I could potentially use for this purpose, but how do I access these via PHPMailer?  (This would work for me as I only use SMTP at this point - however, this would NOT work if other message transport like sendmail was used, so I would prefer a PHPMailer solution)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want individual result codes for individual address, you really need to send each message separately. If you do get errors on some recipients, they will be listed in the ErrorInfo property - look in the `smtpSend` function to see how the error string is assembled. I agree that it's not especially easy to parse that info out. The error messages in PHPMailer are generally more for the developer than the end user, so the translations are not that significant. You can get slightly more information about errors if you enable exceptions rather than relying only on return values.

Comment: Thanks @Synchro. I am sending them separately.  Are you saying that the underlying SMTP codes are in the ErrorInfo?  That seemed to be the case for some but no means all of the phpmailer exceptions.  So unfortunately not usable as the basis for a simple mechanism to identify whether SENT OK, TRY LATER, or MESSAGE FAIL.

Comment: Specifically, I am getting problems due to poor connectivity where several messages are failing due to inability to connect successfully.  I don't want to extend timeouts etc because it is already slow. Nothing wrong with the message, or the connection settings. Just needs to try again until it eventually does go through.  I need a simple way to identify ones which fail like this vs. ones which fail due to more serious issues.

Comment: OK, you've got a fundamental problem here - PHPMailer is not a proper MTA. All that you asked for is normally taken care of by a real mail server which has the ability to queue, retry and repost bounces. So the right way to do this is to submit your messages to a local or nearby mail server and let that deal with the problems, then review the bounces when they come back. That's an appropriate SMTP flow. PHPMailer's primary function is to get messages to your local server, not anything beyond that.

Comment: OK ... well that answers the question then! Shame because it would be really easy for PHPMailer to do, given that it is already managing all the errors in any case , some kind of simple error categorisation could add quite a lot of value.  Guess its time to go find something else then.

Comment: I agree to some extent. I wrote the original exception system, but the maintainer at the time didn't understand it and messed it up. However, even with that in place, you should not be trying to write an MTA in PHP with any library - there are far better solutions available.

Comment: wheels? re-invent? moi? You're 100% right ... thanks!