# Possible PHPMailer Error messages for better error handling

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I understand that PHPMailer will give you an error if the mail fails:

```
    if (!$mail->send()) {
      echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo) . PHP_EOL;
    }
```

And I could use a 'try/catch' processing for the $mail->send.

But is there a list of PHPMailer error messages that I can use for better error handling? I've looked in the PHPMailer docs, and have searched here and other places, but have not found a comprehensive list of possible errors. (There is this question [phpmailer error codes for outcome processing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33408415/1466973) from 2015, but the answer didn't help me.)

Or are the error messages dependent on the mail server?

I'd like to trap certain errors, like an invalid email, or a 'mail send error', etc. And maybe ignore some errors (although I'm not sure which ones to avoid, since I can't find a list of possible errors).

I suppose I could dig through the source code to find them, but wondering if somebody has already complied that information.

So, looking for PHPMailer ErrorInfo values - *or code that you use to catch errors*.

Comment: Invalid email should be trapper earlier - `addAddress` will return false or throw an exception. Many errors can't be determined until you try to send, and in some cases PHP makes it very difficult to find why something has failed, for example anything to do with TLS, where you can often only see the consequences of the error, not the error itself. The single best way to configure PHPMailer is to use SMTP to send to localhost, and then have a local mail server deal with onward delivery. It's faster, safer and more reliable than sending directly.

Comment: You could just look at the code: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/tree/master/src

Comment: @miken32 Not terribly helpful. PHPMailer throws a generic Exception no matter what went wrong. The question was (IMHO) how to extract actionable information from this exception.

Answer (score 1):

**There is no exception list.**

PHPMailer just a wrapper https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/48392076504a2ee4b091d46fec2c3089b71f804a/src/PHPMailer.php#L1632
and error handling depends on a provider

- mail - https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php
- sendmail - https://linux.die.net/man/8/sendmail.sendmail
- smtp - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_SMTP_server_return_codes

**May be useful:**

```php
/**
 * Constructor.
 *
 * @param bool $exceptions Should we throw external exceptions?
 */
```

https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/src/PHPMailer.php#L826

Example

https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/exceptions.phps

Also you can enable debug for dev purposes

https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail.phps#L26